# How to use P\Invoke in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I have number of C++ API's and I want to access them using P\Invoke in VB.Net.Following are the C wrapper written for some of the API's.Can anybody tell me how to use P\Invoke to access these methods in VB.Net.

In wrapper.h:

```
typedef void * VERIFY_HANDLE;
extern VERIFY_HANDLE Verify_Create();
extern void VERIFY_SetVerified(VERIFY_HANDLE, bool);
extern bool VERIFY_GetVerified(VERIFY_HANDLE);
/* etc, etc */
```

In wrapper.c:

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "Verify.h"
VERIFY_HANDLE Verify_Create() { return (VERIFY_HANDLE) new Verify(); }
void SetVerified(VERIFY_HANDLE h, bool b) { ((Verify *)h)->SetVerified(b); }
bool GetVerified(VERIFY_HANDLE h) { return ((Verify *)h)->GetVerified();  }
```

Comment: Have a look at pinvoke.net. They have many signatures listed for using pinvoke and they provide VB.net signatures so you can see how to wrap your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) can create Vb.Net P/Invoke code automatically from that C header file.

Comment: Mark:Can you please tell me what will the signature for 'HRESULT Get_GetLastHR(void *)'.I am using 'Public Shared Function Get_GetLastHR(ByVal param0 As System.IntPtr) As Integer' , but it showing me signature error

Comment: The CodePlex link no longer exists, [here is a new link on GitHub](https://github.com/jaredpar/pinvoke-interop-assistant) but I do not know how to use it... I am now using [CppAst.CodeGen](https://github.com/xoofx/CppAst.CodeGen)

Comment: I think the official GitHub location is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke). Also C# developers now benefit from the tool [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32). It brings in Intellisense and documentation! Let's hope VB.Net gets support too!

Comment: If you download the archive from CodePlex (button at top left) does that include a built P/Invoke Interop Assistant?