# Is it possible to use a c++ class into vb.net code?

Tags: c++, vb.net, class

I have a couple of certain cipher algorithm classes provided by a third agent written in c++ and the architechture of my application is implemented in vb.net. Is it possible to somehow import his classes and use them like a blackbox into my vb.net application?

If not I guess I'll need to re-write my vb.net program to c++ which will be a bit of a mesh.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call C++ from .NET languages using P\Invoke. For using P\Invoke in VB.NET see [How to use P\Invoke in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945375/how-to-use-p-invoke-in-vb-net)

Comment: +1 This is possibly the only *sensible* approach. There are a number of other solutions (such as COM, and other IPC techniques)